Several installation issues 24.04
I have always been a Windows and Debian user.  Windows for the desktop and Debian for my servers.
I have always tried to switch to Ubuntu desktop as soon as there is a major version.  I have always had many bugs and problems.  I would like to take the plunge but I still can't do it with this new version.
First of all I had extreme difficulty launching the USB key, grub appears fine but nothing happens when I launch Ubuntu, only a "_" flashes on the screen.  I finally wrote directly to the hard drive by connecting it via USB but this does not allow the installation to be started on the same drive.  Anyway, I'm going to try to do it again via the USB key.
Then I can't find my keyboard in the "French from Belgium" list and my touchpad doesn't work in multitouch... My PC: Asus G50V.
I'm hesitant to force Windows 11 on it, Ubuntu has already wasted a lot of time...
So, I have three questions:

Is the USB boot bug known?
Is the bug with the lack of multitouch on the touchpad known?
Is the bug with the lack of a "French from Belgium" keyboard known?

Is it possible to resolve these 3 problems?

I’m voting to close this question because there is no question here. Use what works for you, and good luck.

It is an odd choice to put all 4 of your questions in a comment. You are welcome to search https://launchpad.net/ for the first 3. The answer to number 4 is "Yes", given enough time and effort, all bugs are solvable.

I incorporated the questions from Robby's comment two into the question.

Is the bug with the lack of multitouch on the touchpad known? Multitouch gestures work on wayland for quite a few years, but not in XOrg. Try zooming into Firefox in Wayland.

Have you tested whether Debian has the same bugs?

Debian offers me my Belgian keyboard as well as a problem-free installation in French.  But the touchpad is even worse.  What I want is long term support.  That's why I think Ubuntu seems really complicated to install.  The installer does not work, there is an error at the end.  I'll try Debian.  At worst I would go back to Windows 11 afterwards...
